# Add margins with grid R package

Tags: r, margins, r-grid

I don't know how to specify margins for PDF printing with grid R package.

I create a `grid.arrange()` object and I put it in a PDF like this :

```
pdf('test.pdf',11.69,8.27)
grid.arrange(textGrob('text1', gp=gpar(cex=4)),
             ncol=1, main=textGrob('title', gp=gpar(cex=1.5)),
             widths = c(1), heights = c(1))
dev.off()
```

But the title is push at the top edge of the sheet. I would like to add margins. If I add a `textGrob` instead of the `main=` function for the title, I can keep it away from the top but it's not a solution for me because I have to put graphs and they are close to the edge too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arrangeGrob has a viewport argument,

```
vp = viewport(height=unit(0.8, "npc"), 
                          width=unit(5, "cm"))

g = arrangeGrob(textGrob('text1', gp=gpar(cex=4)),
              top = textGrob('title', gp=gpar(cex=1.5)),  
              vp=vp)
grid.newpage()
grid.rect(vp=vp)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I plot it in a pdf (11.69,8.27), I changed this :

```
vp = viewport(height=unit(8.17, "inches"), width=unit(11.59, "inches"))
g$vp = vp
grid.newpage()
grid.rect(vp=vp,gp=gpar(col="white"))
grid.draw(g)
```

Like this, the edges of rectangle is not visible and I have about 1 mm margins.

Comment: that's not really an answer, also, the white rectangle seems pointless , I only put it for illustration.